# Linq Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xdocument.

```
XDocument xd = new XDocument();
var xdocument = XDocument.Parse(@"<Values>
                                <Required>
                                    <DisplayItem>rbProvided</DisplayItem>
                                    <MessageId>38</MessageId>
                                </Required>
                              </Values>");
```

Now, i am trying to check if an element exists in this, if not i need to add it. Here is the code I am trying

```
if(xd.Descendants().Elements("Monkey") != null)
  { Do this }
```

And it keeps telling me:

```
 Sequence Contains No Elements
```

How do I check for existing element correctly?

Comment: what is Xdocument.Read ? you don't even have an element named Monkey. And you are using Descendants like a property.if you want help post your actual code

Comment: This isn't your actual code.  This code won't compile. (You need an @ sign before the XML string, and Xdocument has the wrong case).

Comment: @Selman22 how very observant of you. obviously then, this element does not exist. how do i find that out without throwing an error.

psst... GSerg also used Descendants like a property(obviously a typo) can we lynch him as well?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry I freehanded some code and got it off a little. Wasn't around an IDE, didn't think it would be a huge deal since the intent and question are obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Elements("Monkey")` returns an `IEnumerable` which is not null (hence your check fails), but contains no elements.

You should have done

```
if (xdocument.Descendants.Elements("Monkey").Any())
```

Comment: Thank you very much GSerg. I was not aware that was the function of any

Answer (score 0):

Checking for a specific element, you can code as follows:

```
XDocument xd = new XDocument();
var xdocument = XDocument.Parse(@"<Values>
                                    <Required>
                                        <DisplayItem>rbProvided</DisplayItem>
                                        <MessageId>38</MessageId>
                                    </Required>
                                  </Values>");

if(xdocument.Descendants("DisplayItem").Any())
    Console.WriteLine("Whatever...");
```

Don't forget to include: `using System.Xml.Linq;` & `using System.Linq;`